# Webpack warning: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type (date-nfs)

Tags: webpack, include, warnings, loader, date-fns

I have a problem with my application. I have a website. I use date-fns to show a formatted date based on the user language.

It works great, but I have updated date-fns and since then I have a warning. In my JavaScript code I use:

```js
const locale = require(`date-fns/locale/${props.match.params.lang}`)
```

And with this, I can generate the right format like this:

```js
format(new Date(), 'D MMMM YYYY', { locale })
```

It works, but I dislike this warning I get when webpack is building. Can you help me to understand what's wrong with my code? If it's in the webpack config or the include.

```
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>frontend         | > declare module 'date-fns/locale/fr' { }
>frontend         | | 
>frontend         |  @ ./node_modules/date-fns/locale sync ^\.\/.*$ ./fr/index.d.ts
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/features/weather/components/home-header.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/features/weather/components/home.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/features/weather/containers/home-container.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/features/weather/containers/app.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/features/weather/index.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/app/router.js
>frontend         |  @ ./assets/javascripts/index.js
>frontend         |  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000 ./assets/javascripts/index
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
const locale = require(`date-fns/locale/${props.match.params.lang}/index.js`)