# How to avoid warning `Module parse failed: Unexpected token` comes from date-fns/locale

Tags: webpack, babel-loader, babel-polyfill, date-fns

I'm using `date-fns` in my react application. When building the app with Webpack(4) and babel(7) Below warning appears.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/date-fns/locale/en/index.d.ts 1:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> declare module 'date-fns/locale/en' { }
| 
 @ ./node_modules/date-fns/locale sync ^\.\/.*$ ./en/index.d.ts
```

Following is the code block where I user `date-fns/locale`.

```
import fmt from 'date-fns/format';

export const format = (date, formatStr) =>
  fmt(date, formatStr, {
    locale: require(`date-fns/locale/en`),
  });
```

How to avoid this warning?

Comment: found the way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818219/webpack-warning-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-da